# Highlighting user selected text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jodit

The issue I'm facing is when user selects any text it should get highlighted, so we are trying to fetch the DOM elements of that text using `window.getselction` and wrap them in `<span>` with styling to add background color. It works fine for most of cases, but when selecting list items if we select only one list item then the content inside that `<li>` tag is wrapped in our span and it is working fine, the issue is on selecting multiple `<li>` items then this span tag messes the html of the list and I dont get desired output.

```
function handleSelectedText() {
    var parentOfSel;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
      parentOfSel = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    }
    var deviation = document.createElement("span");
    deviation.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
    deviation.id = "some-id-to-identify-sapn";
    deviation.appendChild(parentOfSel.extractContents());
    parentOfSel.insertNode(deviation);
  }

This function triggers on mouseUp event.
```

**Open to use any package if exits for this as it is being implemented in React JS.**

Comment: Can you provide an example and the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

As today's web application running in a browser with CSS3 support, the `::selection` selector can match your requirement by doing things easily like this:

```
::selection { background-color: cyan }
```

```css
::selection {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<p>Unordered list:</p>

<ul>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Yeah that works but the issue is that I'm working with rich text editor and the a content in the editor  is parsed as a html tags, so i have to persist this selection where user has highlited the text so that if that particular doc is opened again,that highlited text is still there, that's why I'm trying to manipulate the DOM elements.

Comment: Maybe you can try save the selection range instead of manipulate DOM, so you can restore the selection range at the next edit. https://javascript.info/selection-range